# Random array element in F#

Tags: f#

I'm attempting to learn myself up on F#, and I fear I'm not understanding something as well as I should.

I'm trying to recreate the functionality of a book I rather like (Creative Cursing from Royal and Panarese).

In a nutshell, you have two separate wordlists from which two random words can be chosen, resulting in an odd phrase. Simple enough?

Here's what I have:

```
#light

open System
open System.IO

let getWordList file =
  File.ReadAllLines( file )

let getRandArrElement (arr : string[]) =
  let rnd = Random( 0 )
  arr |> Seq.nth (rnd.Next arr.Length)

let wordList1 = getWordList "words1.txt"
let wordList2 = getWordList "words2.txt"

let word1 = getRandArrElement wordList1
let word2 = getRandArrElement wordList2

printf "%s %s" word1 word2
```

It works, too. With the exception that it returns the same phrase every time it's run.

I have a feeling that what it's doing is calculating one random value per call to "getRandArrElement" at compile time, then using that value as THE value (which I think is weird, but what do I know?).

Whats wrong with my logic, and how do I fix it?

Comment: FYI - the `#light` directive is no longer needed as it is the default now.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
let getRandArrElement (arr : string[]) =
  let rnd = Random( 0 )
  arr |> Seq.nth (rnd.Next arr.Length
```

`Random` numbers aren't really truly random. They take a seed value, compute a random number between `0.0` and `1.0`; that new value is used as the next seed. In other words, `Random` i spurely deterministic,  so seeding with the same value over and over yields the same output sequence.

And since you're always constructor a new Random with the same seed, you're getting the same random number as output everytime.

I suggest a few improvements:

- use `let rnd = Random()`. The default constructor uses the system clock as a seed, so that you'll get a different sequence. (Its still possible to get the same sequence. The system clock has a resolution of about 10 ms, so construction two Randoms in that interval will result, with high probability, of being seeded with the same value.

  If you use `let rnd = Random(0)`, even if `rnd` is outside your function, you'll get the same sentences in the exact same order everytime your run your program.
- You can move the declaration of `rnd` outside your function so you're not constructing it over and over. As an alternative, you can write this:

  ```
  let getRandArrElement =
      let rnd = Random()
      fun (arr : string[]) -> ...
  ```

  F# executes all parameterless values when you open a module, so `rnd` will be assigned right away, and `getRandArrElement` is assigned the value of `fun (arr : string[]) -> ...`.
- Use `arr.[index]` instead of `arr |> Seq.nth (rnd.Next arr.Length)`. Its not only more concise, but its also O(1). `Seq.nth` treats it like a sequence, it walks one element at a time until it gets to the element matching the given index, making the operation `O(n)`.

The final result should be something like:

```
let getRandArrElement =
  let rnd = Random()
  fun (arr : string[]) -> arr.[rnd.Next(arr.Length)]
```

Comment: +1 for encapsulating rnd inside the function where it belongs.

Comment: Regarding your last point, surely seq is optimized for when xs is an array?

Answer (score 3):

You are using a new [**Random**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.aspx) with the same seed every time, this is expected behavior - if the same seed is used repeatedly, the same series of numbers is generated.  I would suggest you move the declaration of rnd out of the function, that will solve your problem:

```
let rnd = Random();

let getRandArrElement (arr : string[]) =
  arr |> Seq.nth (rnd.Next arr.Length)
```

Comment: -1, as Juliet points out (as I was about to but pizza waits for no man), moving the `rnd` initialization out of the function like this suffers the same issue you correctly pointed out, but instead of seeing it each time you call the function, you see it each time you run the application.

Comment: Agreed - and edited by removing the seed - I didn't know that F# is computing all parameterless values when you open a module, otherwise I would have left the rnd declaration inside the function as well.